# Why do I get different results when using multiprocessing with an instance method vs with a function?

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

For the following code, which passes an instance method to the `Pool`, the list is empty at the end of the script:

```
import time

from multiprocessing import Pool

class Hello:
    def __init__(self):
        self.result_list=[]

    def f(self,x,y):
        time.sleep(2)
        return x*y


    def log_result(self,result):
        # This is called whenever foo_pool(i) returns a result.
        # result_list is modified only by the main process, not the pool workers.
        print result
        self.result_list.append(result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool()              # start 4 worker processes
    h=Hello()
    for i in range(10):
        pool.apply_async(h.f, args = (i,i, ), callback = h.log_result)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print(h.result_list)
```

With this code, the list is populated as expected.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

def foo_pool(x):
    time.sleep(2)
    return x*x

result_list = []
def log_result(result):
    # This is called whenever foo_pool(i) returns a result.
    # result_list is modified only by the main process, not the pool workers.
    result_list.append(result)

def apply_async_with_callback():
    pool = mp.Pool()
    for i in range(10):
        pool.apply_async(foo_pool, args = (i, ), callback = log_result)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print(result_list)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    apply_async_with_callback()
```

What's different about the two? Why doesn't it work with the instance method?

Answer (score 3):

If you actually try to fetch the result of one of you `apply_async` calls, you'll see that they're all failing with this error:

```
cPickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'instancemethod'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.instancemethod failed
```

This is because in Python 2.x, instance methods aren't picklable by default, so trying to pass the instance method `h.f` to the worker process fails. This is actually fixed in Python 3, but you can backport the behavior to Python 2 quite easily, using the [`copy_reg`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy_reg.html) module:

```
import time

from multiprocessing import Pool
import copy_reg
import types

def _reduce_method(m):
    if m.__self__ is None:
        return getattr, (m.__class__, m.__func__.__name__)
    else:
        return getattr, (m.__self__, m.__func__.__name__)

copy_reg.pickle(types.MethodType, _reduce_method)

class Hello:
    def __init__(self):
        self.result_list=[]

    def f(self,x,y):
        time.sleep(2)
        return x*y


    def log_result(self, result):
        print(result)
        self.result_list.append(result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool()
    h = Hello()
    for i in range(10):
        pool.apply_async(h.f, args = (i,i), callback=h.log_result)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print(h.result_list)
```

Output:

```
0
4
49
25
1
16
36
9
64
81
[0, 4, 49, 25, 1, 16, 36, 9, 64, 81]
```

Comment: Your answer is a simplified version of what the `dill` package does to augment `pickle` -- all you have to do is `import dill`, and then pickle knows how to serialize instance methods.  Since in `python-2.x`, `multiprocessing` defaults to `cPickle`, I had to fork `multiprocessing` into the `pathos` package… but `pathos` basically then gives you a version of `multiprocessing` that can serialize almost any object in python.  See: https://github.com/uqfoundation

Comment: Perfect for me. This is a viable workaround for 2.7 and should be accepted as answer.